# The file format and extension of <filename>.xls don't match -- apache-poi 4.1.2

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am creating xls with apache-poi version 4.1.2. when I do with junit it is working correctly but if I use tomee with container then the generated file is showing an error like

[image: Screen shot while open xls]

> The file format and extension of <filename>.xls don't match

- Java version 1.8
- tomee-plus 1.7.5
- K8s docker container
- Using HSSFWorkbook

  File outputFile = new File(dir, fileParameter.getFileName());
  if (outputFile.exists() && !FileUtils.deleteFile(outputFile)) {
  LOG.warn("Cannot delete");
  }
  try (final HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook()) {
  final HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(SUMMARY_SHEET_NAME);
  //Header Row
  int rowNum = 0;
  int cellNum = 0;
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
  row.createCell(cellNum++).setCellValue("TEST1");
  row.createCell(cellNum++).setCellValue("TEST2");
  row.createCell(cellNum++).setCellValue("TEST3");
  row.createCell(cellNum++).setCellValue("TEST4");
  row.createCell(cellNum++).setCellValue("TEST5");

  ```
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: Without your code it's a bit hard to see what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Thanks  @Gagravarr and added code in the original post.

Comment: If you save the file, and run the Apache Tika App in `--detect` mode, what type does Tika report it being?

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I found the issue while doing SFTP we are changing the encoding type caused this issue.  Thanks for your response.